# ATtiny85 Comparator C interrupt on timer 1

Tags: interrupt, timers, attiny

I have a program that uses Timer1 comparator A in CTC mode. I realize that I need to set OCR1C for the timer to reset at given value. However there is no such thing as an interrupt generated by timer1 counter matching OCR1C value.

Moreover, if I enable CTC and set for example OCR1A to 10, and OCR1C to 50, the interrupt handler `ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)` will be triggered when the counter reaches OCR1C value, not OCR1A. I'm really confused...

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

EDIT:

Here is the program that I'm using.
main program:

```cpp
#include "avr/interrupt.h"

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  PORTB ^= (1<<PB0); //toggle pin 
}

void setup() {
  cli();
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //prescaler value 8192 sets one clock tick to about 1ms
  TCCR1 |= (1<<CS13)|(1<<CS12)|(1<<CS11)|(0<<CS10);
  //turn CTC mode on
  bitSet( TCCR1, CTC1 );
  //set comparatorA value
  OCR1A = 10;
  //enable compA interrupts
  bitSet(TIMSK, OCIE1A);
  //set comp C value
  OCR1C = 19;
  // initialize counter 1 on 0
  TCNT1 = 0;
  pinMode( 0, OUTPUT );
  digitalWrite( 0, HIGH );
  sei();
}

int main() {
  setup();
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(1) {
    }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: You wrote “_there is no such thing as an interrupt generated by timer1 counter matching OCR1C value_”. Quoting the datasheet: “_In PWM mode (either PWM1A=1 or PWM1B=1) the bit TOV1 is set (one) when compare match occurs between Timer/Counter1 and data value in OCR1C_”. TOV1 is the flag that triggers the TIMER1\_OVF interrupt. Note that you can enable PWM mode while keeping the PWM outputs disconnected from their pins (bits COM1xy cleared).

Comment: @EdgarBonet Alright, but in non-PWM mode theoretically matchA interrupt should be called whenever TCNT1 reaches OCR1A value, right? But this does not happend. In fact it is triggered only when it reaches OCR1C

Comment: I uploaded your program to an ATtiny25V (essentially a slower ATtiny85 with less memory) and I get exactly the expected behavior: a square wave on pin 0 with a period of roughly 328 ms. Note that the clock runs at 1 MHz, as the CKDIV8 fuse is programmed by default.

Comment: @EdgarBonet So you get a square wave that is high for OCR1A and low for OCR1C-OCR1A ticks?

Comment: I get 50% duty cycle, as expected from reading your code.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Ok so change the value of OCR1C to 50 and see if duty cycle changes

Comment: Did it. Period became 838 ms, duty cycle didn't change, just as expected.

Comment: @EdgarBonet But... it should change, right? Because only function that changes PB0 is ISR attached to matchA interrupt. For rest of time it should be LOW. When Counter1 reaches OCR1C, timer1 resets and whole thing starts over. If this is right, duty cycle shoulde definitly change. Correct me please if im wrong

Comment: Well, you are wrong. The _only_ thing that changes PB0 is the ISR: every time the timer hits the OCR1A value, the pin toggles. When Counter 1 reaches OCR1C, timer1 resets and this has _no effect whatsoever_ on PB0. If you want the timer to toggle a pin all by itself, you should use a PWM mode rather than an interrupt.

Comment: So if OCRC1A is 10 and OCRC1C is 50, pin toggles at 10, resets at 50, and then toggles at 10 etc... so duty cycle shoulde be 80% on one cycle and 20% at next. Right?

Comment: No. Pin toggles at 10, then pin toggles at 10, then pin toggles at 10... Duty cycles is 50%. Let me repeat it again: Timer 1 resetting _has no effect whatsoever on PB0_. Repeat: **no effect whatsoever**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57429/discussion-between-em-ka-and-edgar-bonet).